# the ideal contains some power of the unique prime ideal containing it

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, noetherian

Let $R$ be a Noetherian ring, and $I$ an ideal such that there exists a unique prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ containing $I$. Show that $I$ contains some power of $\mathfrak{p}.$

In this question, I couldn't use the uniqueness of the prime ideal, and being that $R$ is a Noetherian ring. Could anyone give some hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`No need to assume "there exists a unique prime ideal p containing I" but assume "there exists a unique *minimal* prime ideal p containing I".`

1- We need  "$R$ is a Noetherian", to have $(\sqrt I)^n\subseteq I;$ for some $n\in \mathbb N$. (This is proposition 7.14 of Atiyah-Macdonald).
+
2- By "uniqueness of the prime ideal containing $I$", we have $\sqrt I = p$. (Proposition 1.14 of Atiyah-Macdonald says *The radical of an ideal is intersection of prime ideals containing it.* ).

Answer (score 6):

Alex's solution is the most straightforward. One can also observe that $R/I$ is a local ring of dimension $0$, since $I$ is contained in a unique prime (which, upon modding out by $I$, becomes the maximal ideal of $R/I$). And a Noetherian ring of dimension $0$ is an Artin ring, in which every non-trivial ideal is nilpotent. Thus $\mathfrak p/I$ is nilpotent in $R/I$.

Comment: This is a lovely solution, Bruno. Thanks for sharing it!

Comment: @Alex Thanks! Yours is much more illuminating though.

Comment: I'd rather say that this is an unnecessarily complicated proof, using big guns like "a Noetherian ring of dimension 0 is an Artin ring" in order to get such a small result. (Only to balance the first comment which is too enthusiastic in my humble opinion.)

Comment: @user26857 I agree myself!

Comment: *... a Noetherian ring of dimension $0$ is an Artin ring, in which every nontrivial ideal is nilpotent.*  I don't think this is quite what you meant. Plenty of artinian rings have nonnilpotent ideals. The local ones don't, of course, but the sentence doesn't clearly express that.

Answer (score 5):

Consider the quotient ring $R/I$, and let $\pi \colon R \to R/I$ be the canonical quotient homomorphism. The nilradical of $R/I$ is the image under $\pi$ of the intersection of all prime ideals of $R$ containing $I$. Since there is a unique prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ containing $I$, the nilradical of $R/I$ is $\pi(\mathfrak{p})$. Now, this means that every element of $\pi(\mathfrak{p})$ is nilpotent in $R/I$. Since $R$ is noetherian, $R/I$ is also noetherian, so $\pi(\mathfrak{p})$ is finitely generated by elements $x_{1}, \ldots, x_{k}$. Can you wrap it up from here to show that every element of $\pi(\mathfrak{p})$ vanishes when raised to a sufficiently large power $N \in \mathbb{N}$, thus showing that $\mathfrak{p}^{N} \subset I$?